# Cannot access ImageProcessor .net library documentation

Tags: c#, imageprocessor

Hello every one kindly help me on ImageProcessor API documentation. It is downloaded but not showing detail. Just the index of the [API Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQDH1.png) is visible.

Comment: How did you install _ImageProcessor_ library and its documentation? Through NuGet? Also mention the exact package name with version please.

Comment: This is from [http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/).  Clicking on the API Documentation button will cause a download of a CHM file.  It appears that the CHM file is corrupt, you could contact the author of this project.

Comment: Alternatively, if you click on the ImageFactory link, then it navigates towards a web version of the API, those seem to work.

Comment: Hey Naveed, How about marking the answer as correct?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor/#about)

> Remember to r-click and unblock the file on download

Windows will block chm files downloaded from the internet for security reasons. You need to unblock the file before use.